# Create table throws an error

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Hi I am trying to create a table using SQL in Mysql but I keep getting an error.Here is my code:

```
USE e-commerce
  CREATE TABLE `categories` (
`id` SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`category` VARCHAR( 30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `category` (`category`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When I try to run this in phpmyadmin SQL console I get this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE `categories` ( `id` SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `category` ' at line 2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add semicolon after `use`

```
USE e-commerce;
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category` VARCHAR( 30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `category` (`category`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 2):

Missing semi-colon

```
 USE e-commerce;
  CREATE TABLE `categories` (
`id` SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`category` VARCHAR( 30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `category` (`category`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code you have 2 queries. You should always end query with a semicolon.

So try the following

```
USE e-commerce;
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
`id` SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`category` VARCHAR( 30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `category` (`category`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```